# Не могу никак понять, чего от меня хочет это существо

Tags: python, discord.py

```
bot.remove_command(help)
@bot.command(pass_context= True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator= False)
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Команды", color=0x2f38b1)
    embed.add_field(name="*cat", value="Показать кота", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="*ban", value="Для админов", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="*kick", value="Для админов", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="Kilka21#5529 (C)")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


iscord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам долго долбился с этой фигней, но сдался. В итоге погуглил, и вот нашел ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62644195/discord-py-change-the-default-help-command

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Answer (score 0):

Я уже понял в чём проблема..
Я забыл ковычки добавить